# Why does the host command not resolve entries in /etc/hosts?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system

I have the following `/etc/hosts` file on a ubuntu 12.04 machine

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
10.248.27.66 ec2-50-112-220-110.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com puppetmaster

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

However the host command does not resolve the name `puppetmaster` correctly, while the telnet command is does

```
root@ip-10-248-34-162:/home/ubuntu# host puppetmaster
Host puppetmaster not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

root@ip-10-248-34-162:/home/ubuntu# telnet puppetmaster 8140
Trying 10.248.27.66...
Connected to ec2-50-112-220-110.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Why does the host command not resolve entries in /etc/hosts?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The `host` program uses `libresolv` to perform a DNS query directly, i.e., does not use `gethostbyname`.

Most programs, when attempting to connect to another host, invoke the `gethostbyname` system call or a similar function. This function obeys the configuration of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. This file has a line which in Ubuntu 12.04 defaults to the following:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

which means that it will first use `/etc/hosts`, then fall back to DNS queries.

If you want to perform a host lookup this way, you can do this with `getent hosts`.  For example:

```
$ getent hosts serverfault.com
198.252.206.16  serverfault.com
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Kvisle, but I'm still a little confused.  The line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` looked like this `hosts:          files dns` and I changed it to `hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4` however in both cases `/etc/hosts` is not queried, instead it appears direct dns queries are made.  How can I ensure that `/etc/hosts` will be queried first when using a command like `dig` or `host`?

Comment: You can't.  dig/host uses DNS directly.  If you need to do a namelookup that checks the hosts-file first, you have to use `getent hosts` or something else that uses `gethostbyname()`

Comment: Oh I see, my bad, I got it now =)

Comment: I believe that nowadays one should be using `getent ahosts` instead of `getent hosts` because `getent hosts` uses `gethostbyaddr()` or `gethostbyname*()` which are obsolete. If I have understood correctly, `getent hosts` emulates how old UNIX C programs used to work and `getent ahosts` emulates the way moderm programs should work.

Comment: But is there a way to make host command use also /etc/hosts?

Comment: @Kornel: `host`

Answer (score 13):

Because the `host` utility is exclusively a DNS lookup utility.

Most applications use the library calls `getaddrinfo` or `gethostbyname`. These libraries interrogate a file called `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to determine the lookup priority and policy of how to perform different lookups.

Typically `/etc/nsswitch.conf` contains the line

```
hosts:        files dns
```

Which tells a program to first interrogate `/etc/hosts` and then interrogate DNS if unsuccessful.

Since hosts does exclusively DNS lookups it does not peek into `/etc/hosts` to do the lookup.

Comment: I suppose "Since hosts does..." is a typo for "Since `host` does...".

Answer (score 4):

You will find that `dig` and `nslookup` behave the same way as `host`.

The reason for this is that the purpose of all of these commands is to do DNS lookups, not to look in files.

Most other programs use the operating system's name resolver which consults `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and then (if required) `/etc/resolv.conf` to decide how to resolve the hostname you are requesting.  (This is a simplification, there are other options.)  The `nsswitch.conf` file usually puts precedence on local files rather than DNS.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93808/dig-vs-nslookup

Answer (score -1):

check the file /etc/nsswitch.conf and look for the line starting with word "hosts"? Do you see the word "files" on this line ? If yes, is it before or after the word "dns" ?

On a normal system, this line should be something like

```
hosts      files dns
```

if yours is not present or in different order, that might be your problem.

Comment: It's present and looks like this `hosts:          files dns`