# Locally resolve a name in a DSN lookup (Host not found: 3(NXDOMAIN))

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, host, resolve

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 Server virtual machine in which I would like to resolve a symbolic name to an IP address locally (i.e., the machine itself should provide the mapping).

The mapping is the following:

```
mon0 --> 127.0.0.1
```

I already have this entry in `/etc/hosts`:

```
# file /etc/hosts
[other entries]
127.0.1.1   mon0
```

so I can `ping mon0` correctly.

What I cannot do is `host mon0`:

```
$ host mon0
Host mon0 not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

From [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/498505/216500) I understand that `host` is using `libresolv` rather than `gethostbyname` (that is why `ping` works and `host` doesn't).

I would like to make `host mon0` working correctly.

What is a simple solution to achieve this? Since everything is known, static and local, I hope there is no need to run a nameserver :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dnsmasq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq) should do exactly what you want and reads your local hosts file.

Comment: It turns out the solution to my problem was just `sudo apt-get install dnsmasq`. With the `/etc/hosts` file already containing the necessary entries, I am now able to resolve the names! Thanks.